# retrieve only uploaded files in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How can we retrieve only the uploaded files from the [Request](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#request-and-base-request) object?

Example: We can retrieve the JSON body from the request with the help of [**`json()`**](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.json) coroutine,

```
json_body = await request.json()
```

Similarly, Can I have the uploaded files without inspecting the **`.post()`** coroutine?

**Note:**
I have found the same/similar implementations in other frameworks
1. Django - [**`request.FILES`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)
2. Flask - [**`request.files`**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#file-uploads)

Comment: You should use [MultipartReader](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/multipart.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### Workaround

I have created a ***decorator*** function that parses the files from **`request.post()`** and then assign to the **`.files`** attribute

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web_request import FileField


def set_files(function):
    async def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            request = args[1]  # class based handler
        except IndexError:
            request = args[0]  # function based handler

        files = {}
        form_data = await request.post()
        for field_name, field_value in form_data.items():
            if isinstance(field_value, FileField):
                files[field_name] = field_value
        request.files = files
        return await function(*args)

    return wrapper


@set_files
async def index(request):
    files = request.files
    return web.Response(text='Hello Aiohttp!')
```